# How do I install my android app on my HTC Magic?

Tags: android, sideloading

I am interested in developing an app for my HTC Magic (Android) phone.
Using instructions on [android's developer site](http://developer.android.com), I installed eclipse with the right plugins, got created the AVD and wrote my first Hello World app which ran in the AVD. I would now like to install that Hello World app on my HTC Magic, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that. I've managed to create a signed .apk file and I've stored that file on the SD card of my phone, but still I can't install it.

Can anyone please help me?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Option #1: Connect your Magic to your development machine. There is an option when you run the app from Eclipse that lets you pick where to run it -- choose the phone. Sorry, but I'm not an Eclipse user, so I do not recall the specific steps.

Option #2: Connect your Magic to your development machine. From the command line, run `adb install path/to/your.apk` (substituting in an appropriate path to your APK file). If the SDK `tools/` directory is in your PATH, you can run that command from anywhere, otherwise you will need to run it from `tools/`.

Option #3: Download a file manager program from the Android Market onto your Magic, and use that to install the APK file as found on your SD card.

Comment: Just so it's clear, Option #1 won't be running your signed APK, it'll be running an APK signed with the development key, just as if it were on the emulator.

Answer (score -1):

The `.apk` file is a kind of install file. Just use a file browser on your phone to "open" it, and it should install the app for you.